# Syntax error in vba excel code

Tags: vba, excel

I am adding a button in my excel sheet for adding an employee with above used formulas.

First two formulas in the below code work perfect but last one giving syntax error.

My code is :

```
Private Sub AddEmployee_Click()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A35").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A35:AJ35").Select
    Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AJ35").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SpeDays(C35:AG35,9)"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AI35").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(AI35>=10,10,AI35)"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH35").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIF(C35:AG35,">=4000")"
```

Comment: Is your error only in the last one?

Comment: On a side note:  you can remove the `select` and `activecell` and join the two lines - `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A35").EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown`

Answer (score 3):

The problem are your quotes inside the formula. Use double quotes as a solution:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIF(C35:AG35, "">=4000"")"
```

Comment: but excel file return formula like this : =IF(AI36>=10,10,AH36)

Comment: it is showing application defined or object defined error

Comment: IT works brother. I have made some mistakes, now identified. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the below code as well

```
Activecell.Formula = "=Countif(C35:AG35," & chr(34) & ">=4000" & chr(34) & ")"
```

Output will be:

`=Countif(C35:AG35,">=4000")`

Comment: it is showing application defined or object defined error

Comment: @PratyushKumar - There's typo, change`AG3,5` to `AG35,`

Comment: Is there any way to apply the same code for last row determined automatically in place of A35 OR AJ35....

Comment: LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

For this, you need to have a fixed row, either its in A coloumn or AJ column.

Thanks

Comment: @nishit dey- for this i have to put only $ with A or AJ. am i right